# check header Authorization on Restler API framework

Tags: php, api, rest

I want to extend Restler to check if a valid value of custom header Authorization was passed. I am having trouble in getting around the fix, I tried this, but no chance:

```
class AuthenticateMe implements iAuthenticate() {

function __isAuthenticated() {
    //return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH_KEY']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH_KEY']==AuthenticateMe::KEY ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        if($header == "Authorization") {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            //return FALSE;
            throw new RestException(404);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me quickly fix your **custom auth header** example

```
class HeaderAuth implements iAuthenticate{
    function __isAuthenticated(){
        //we are only looking for a custom header called 'Auth'
        //but $_SERVER prepends HTTP_ and makes it all uppercase
        //thats why we need to look for 'HTTP_AUTH' instead
        //also do not use header 'Authorization'. It is not
        //included in PHP's $_SERVER variable
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH']=='password';
    }
}
```

I have tested it to make sure it works!

Here is how to make it work with *Authorization* header, it works only on apache servers

```
 class Authorization implements iAuthenticate{
    function __isAuthenticated(){
        $headers =  apache_request_headers();
        return isset($headers['Authorization']) && $headers['Authorization']=='password';
    }
}
```

I figured out that PHP converts `Authorization` header into `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST']` or `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` depending on the type of auth request (digest or basic), we can use the following `.htaccess` file to enable the `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` header

DirectoryIndex index.php

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
</IfModule>
```

important part is **RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]**

Now our example can be simplified to:

```
class Authorization implements iAuthenticate{
    function __isAuthenticated(){
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']=='password';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luracast, I already did this kind of approach, what matters is that say the client insist on the use of header 'Authorization'.

Comment: @Dee Here you go, I've updated my answer with a working example that uses Authorization in the header

Comment: Hello Luracast, I try to implement this into your crud example. However it seems that, the Authorization is bypass. I tried this `class Authorization implements iAuthenticate{
    function __isAuthenticated(){
        $headers =  apache_request_headers();
        return isset($headers['Authorization']) && $headers['Authorization']=='password';
    }
}` because I doubt my .htaccess is ignored. But still no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

#### Header Authentication

there are three ways to do it

1. HTTP Basic Authentication
2. HTTP Digest Authentication
3. Roll our own using custom HTTP headers

You can read more from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Restler 1.0 had a Digest Authentication example. I've modified to make it work with Restler 2.0

```
class DigestAuthentication implements iAuthenticate
{
    public $realm = 'Restricted API';
    public static $user;
    public $restler;


    public function __isAuthenticated()
    {
        //user => password hardcoded for convenience
        $users = array('admin' => 'mypass', 'guest' => 'guest');
        if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$this->realm.'",qop="auth",nonce="'.
            uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($this->realm).'"');
            throw new RestException(401, 'Digest Authentication Required');
        }

        // analyze the PHP_AUTH_DIGEST variable
        if (!($data = DigestAuthentication::http_digest_parse($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) ||
        !isset($users[$data['username']]))
        {
            throw new RestException(401, 'Wrong Credentials!');
        }


        // generate the valid response
        $A1 = md5($data['username'] . ':' . $this->realm . ':' . $users[$data['username']]);
        $A2 = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].':'.$data['uri']);
        $valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$data['nonce'].':'.$data['nc'].':'.$data['cnonce'].':'.$data['qop'].':'.$A2);

        if ($data['response'] != $valid_response)
        {
            throw new RestException(401, 'Wrong Credentials!');
        }
        // ok, valid username & password
        DigestAuthentication::$user=$data['username'];
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Logs user out of the digest authentication by bringing the login dialog again
     * ignore the dialog to logout
     *
     * @url GET /user/login
     * @url GET /user/logout
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$this->realm.'",qop="auth",nonce="'.
        uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($this->realm).'"');
        die('Digest Authorisation Required');
    }


    // function to parse the http auth header
    private function http_digest_parse($txt)
    {
        // protect against missing data
        $needed_parts = array('nonce'=>1, 'nc'=>1, 'cnonce'=>1, 'qop'=>1, 'username'=>1, 'uri'=>1, 'response'=>1);
        $data = array();
        $keys = implode('|', array_keys($needed_parts));

        preg_match_all('@(' . $keys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

        foreach ($matches as $m) {
            $data[$m[1]] = $m[3] ? $m[3] : $m[4];
            unset($needed_parts[$m[1]]);
        }

        return $needed_parts ? false : $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Arul, thanks for the comment. Aside from what the RESTler suggested, how do you test your API server?